# asp LinkButton not producing code behind when clicked on

Tags: asp.net

I am currently using Visual Studio 2019, I am using asp Link Buttons, when you normally double click on the onclick VS will open the .cs page with the event already defined. 
I am unable to do this, Has anyone come across this problem?

```
<asp:LinkButton class="ftr" ID="LoginBtn" runat="server" onClick ="LoginBtn" Visible="True">Login</asp:LinkButton> &nbsp;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many causes when dynamic controls stops generating events in .cs file on double click. One of major is please look at your page directive correctly pointing the **CodeBehind** file and where it **inherits**.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="projectname.index" %>
```

in above code **index** is page name, and **index.aspx.cs** is code behind file, so my cs file look like:

```
namespace projectname
{
public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
 }
}
```